# PDF File could not be opened and possibly corrupted

Tags: windows, pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I am using windows server.  This server has pdf files.  Couldn't open one of those pdf files.  I tried to open it using adobe acrobat reader.  That is when the error occurred:

> "Adobe acrobat reader DC could not open .pdf  because it is either not supported file type or because the file has been damaged.

I tried to open it using alternate pdf reader such as "FoxitReader" but failed.

I tried to open it using pdftk tool  and it couldn't open it.  Here is the log of that tool:

```
2016-11-20 15:31:07 INFO: Starting PDFtk
2016-11-20 15:31:12 WARNING: Trouble finding page count for PDF: 27BB44FA-A01C-4028-A7D7-90B8477E1DDF{2C601900-A9E6-4AE0-B9A8-A9A5E9F68D7C}0.pdf pdftk output: Error: Unable to find file.
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
   C:\Users\mtaha\Desktop\health check forms\27BB44FA-A01C-4028-A7D7-90B8477E1DDF{2C601900-A9E6-4AE0-B9A8-A9A5E9F68D7C}0.pdf
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.

2016-11-20 15:31:12 INFO: Unable to open this PDF, so it will be removed from the input.

Removing PDF: 27BB44FA-A01C-4028-A7D7-90B8477E1DDF{2C601900-A9E6-4AE0-B9A8-A9A5E9F68D7C}0.pdf
```

Then I tried the following online pdf repair tool https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/repair.aspx

However, it says that the header file was not found.  So it couldn't open it.

Any other method to open this PDF file?

I thought of sharing the following content because I thought you might ask for it.  I opened the PDF file using notepad to see the message.  I am sharing part of the long message (error):

```
e() for servlet LogServlet threw exception
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 25, Size: 25
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
    at com.primavera.exponline.common.base.LogCommand.getMain(Unknown Source)
    at com.primavera.exponline.servlet.LogServlet.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.primavera.exponline.servlet.LogServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:310)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:398)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:241)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at com.primavera.exponline.servlet.ExpActionServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
```

Comment: This is your question, buried in the body of your post: "Any other method to open this PDF file?".

Comment: So I should have written it in the beginning.  I have no idea why the file not opening. Is the PDF file corrupted or there is another way of opening it?

Comment: If that's what you see opening the PDF with notepad, then it is not a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

> I opened the PDF file using notepad to see the message.

A PDF usually starts with %PDF-1.4 (or %PDF-1.3 etc for older versions)

```
e() for servlet LogServlet threw exception
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 25, Size: 25
at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
```

If you see text like this then the answer is simple. This is not a PDF file. It might have the extension PDF but its contents are not PDF.

Instead it looks flike some active java was untended to be used to generate the PDF file. That failed and you get the error output instead of the PDF contents.

> Then I tried the following online pdf repair tool https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/repair.aspx

Since it is not a PDF file there is nothing a PDF repair tool can do about it.

> However, it says that the header file was not found. So it couldn't open it.

In which it is correct. You file does not start with %PDF

> Any other method to open this PDF file?

Nope since it is not a PDF file.